# Locally hosted Parse Server Cloud Code Invalid Function

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

I had set up the local Parse Server and I added my cloud folder containing, `app.js`, `main.js`, `node_modules`, `package.json`, and `views`  inside the main folder.

I repeatedly get this error, `Error handling request: ParseError { code: 141, message: 'Invalid function.' } code=141, message=Invalid function`

Comment: Share relevant parts from main.js and code used to call the methods.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you are referencing your localhost server and restart your local server every time you update cloud code